# How can I fix 'npx hardhat' not returning desired menu?

Tags: node.js, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

On hardhat's website and the tutorial i am watching, they both say run `"npm init -y"` then `"npm install --save-dev hardhat"` then `"npx hardhat"` you will be returned a menu shown here: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/project-setup . However i am not being returned this menu, instead i am being returned this:

Hardhat version 2.14.0

Usage: hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS]  [TASK OPTIONS]

GLOBAL OPTIONS:

```
  --config              A Hardhat config file.
  --emoji               Use emoji in messages.
  --flamegraph          Generate a flamegraph of your Hardhat tasks
  --help                Shows this message, or a task's help if its name is provided
  --max-memory          The maximum amount of memory that Hardhat can use.
  --network             The network to connect to.
  --show-stack-traces   Show stack traces (always enabled on CI servers).
  --tsconfig            A TypeScript config file.
  --typecheck           Enable TypeScript type-checking of your scripts/tests
  --verbose             Enables Hardhat verbose logging
  --version             Shows hardhat's version.
```

AVAILABLE TASKS:

```
check                 Check whatever you need
  clean                 Clears the cache and deletes all artifacts
  compile               Compiles the entire project, building all artifacts
  console               Opens a hardhat console
  coverage              Generates a code coverage report for tests
  flatten               Flattens and prints contracts and their dependencies. If no file is passed, all the contracts in the project will be flattened.
  gas-reporter:merge
  help                  Prints this message
  node                  Starts a JSON-RPC server on top of Hardhat Network
  run                   Runs a user-defined script after compiling the project
  test                  Runs mocha tests
  typechain             Generate Typechain typings for compiled contracts
  verify                Verifies contract on Etherscan
```

To get help for a specific task run: npx hardhat help [task].

I would like to get the menu shown in the website when i run "npx hardhat". Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried opening a new project and starting over but it did not help. I checked online and also got nothing. Please help.

Comment: npx hardhat works for me on v2.10.0 I would downgrade to that version